# How to install java on CentOS VPS through ssh

Tags: ssh, centos, java

I wrote a little Java servlet and, in order to run it, acquired a VPS which runs Centos 5. Now, in order to run it, I guess the first thing to do is to install the latest JRE. I have ssh access and googled the web for tutorials on how to install Java through ssh, but most of them are very old, have broken links, or are very confusing.

Can anyone give a simple step by step instruction on how to install the latest JRE through ssh?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the OpenJDK right through the CentOS repositories, by running `yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk` as root.  If you must have the <strike>Sun</strike>Oracle Java packages, visit the [java download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and follow the links for downloading the JRE.

The advantage of using the OpenJDK is that you get updates automatically through CentOS.  CentOS also has packages for Tomcat 5, if you were planning on using that.